# Instagram tracking in Google Sheets. Error: jsonStr = source.match(r)[2];

Tags: json, google-apps-script, google-sheets, instagram

Since Aug 21, my Instagram tracking in Google Sheets is throwing this error.

jsonStr = source.match(r)[2];  Cannot read property "2" from null. Does anyone have a solution for this?

```
function insertFollowerCount() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(this.sheetName);
  accountdata = getInstagramData(this.instagramAccountName);
  sheet.appendRow([Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT", "yyyy-MM-dd"), accountdata.followerCount, accountdata.followCount, accountdata.mediaCount]);  
 };

function getInstagramData(username) {
  var r = new RegExp('<script type="text\/javascript">' + 
                   '([^{]+?({.*profile_pic_url.*})[^}]+?)' +
                   '<\/script>');
  var url = "https://www.instagram.com/" + username
  var source = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText();
  var jsonStr = source.match(r)[2];
  var data = JSON.parse(jsonStr);
  console.log('data', data);
  var oldVariantOfData = data['entry_data']['ProfilePage'][0];
  console.log('oldVariantOfData', oldVariantOfData);

  return {
    followerCount : oldVariantOfData.graphql.user.edge_followed_by.count,
    followCount : oldVariantOfData.graphql.user.edge_follow.count, 
    mediaCount : oldVariantOfData.graphql.user.edge_owner_to_timeline_media.count
  };
}

jsonStr = source.match(r)[2];  Cannot read property "2" from null. Does anyone have a solution for this?
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same issue since 8/21/2019. From what I can find, the last time the code broke the RegExp needed to be updated. I'm assuming this is the case again, but that's beyond my understanding.